# Central angle of a sector of a circle after unraveling a cone.

Tags: calculus

I am reading the Stewart textbook on calc and I see this quote:

[image]

Where does the formula $\theta = \frac{2\pi r}{l}$ come from? Formulas that I know of are:

area of a sector = $\frac{1}{2} r^2 \theta$ which makes sense... if $\theta = 2\pi$ then this formula is $\pi r^2$ which is the area formula we all know for a circle.

But where does the theta formula come from? Also what does $r$ represent here? $L$ and $r$ are both the radius of the circle?

Comment: There are two circles in this problem...

Comment: explain further @YvesDaoust?

Comment: Look at the figure, there are two different circles.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the unit circle. Then an arc of length $\alpha$ is spanned by an angle measuring $\alpha$ radiants. More generally, if the radius is $R$, then the angle $\alpha$ spans an arc of length $\alpha R$. In the figure, the arc is long $2 \pi r$, the radius is $l$ and the angle is $\theta$.